# FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" + Owncloud

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, fastcgi, owncloud

I experience a weird error with my nginx/php5-fpm configuration. I already posted this question on the owncloud forums and asked the nginx forum, but they have no idea. As i searched serverfault, the suggestions about this topic did not directly apply to my problem, because they all share a wrongly configured location block, which i think, is not the case here (i took the config directly from the owncloud documentation).

So what is the problem?

My nginx `error.log` is filled with these:

```
"FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: MY IP, server: MY DOMAIN, request: "GET /core/img/actions/history.svg HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "MY HOSTNAME/DOMAIN", referrer: "MY DOMAIN"
```

Owncloud runs in a subdirectory, `/srv/www/owncloud,` the root points to `/srv/www`. If i point the same configuration to root `/srv/www/owncloud`; the same error is caused, but this time it reads:

```
FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: IP, server: HOSTNAME, request: "GET /owncloud/owncloud/status.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock:", host: "HOSTNAME"
```

Notice the duplicate "owncloud" path...the file, php is looking for, is located at /srv/www/owncloud/status.php (may as well be the .gif from the error above, it is kind of random), not at /owncloud/owncloud...but when i revert the document root to /src/www, php omits the /owncloud path completely! It is driving me nuts...

My nginx config looks this way:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes auto;

pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    multi_accept on;
    use epoll;
}


http {
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    include mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
}
```

And my owncloud - site config:

```
upstream php-handler {
    server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}

server {
    listen MY IP:4433 ssl;
    server_name MY DOMAIN;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/owncloud/owncloud_full.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/owncloud/owncloud.key;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/owncloud/dhparam.pem;

    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/ssl/owncloud/comodo_full_chain.pem;
    resolver DNS SERVERS valid=300s;
    resolver_timeout 10s;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/ssl/owncloud/comodo_full_chain.pem;
    resolver 95.129.51.51 80.244.244.244 valid=300s;
    resolver_timeout 10s;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
    ssl_ciphers *LIST OF SECURE CIPHERS*;

    ssl_session_timeout 10m;
    ssl_session_cache off;
    ssl_session_tickets on;
    ssl_session_ticket_key /etc/nginx/ticketkey;

    # Add headers to serve security related headers
  add_header Strict-Transport-Security 'max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload' always;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Robots-Tag none;

    # Path to the root of your installation
    root /srv/www;

    # set max upload size
    client_max_body_size 10G;
    fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;

    # Disable gzip to avoid the removal of the ETag header
    gzip off;

    index index.php;
    error_page 403 /core/templates/403.php;
    error_page 404 /core/templates/404.php;

    rewrite ^/.well-known/carddav /remote.php/carddav/ permanent;
    rewrite ^/.well-known/caldav /remote.php/caldav/ permanent;

    # set max upload size
    client_max_body_size 10G;
    fastcgi_buffers 64 4K;

    # Disable gzip to avoid the removal of the ETag header
    gzip off;

    index index.php;
    error_page 403 /core/templates/403.php;
    error_page 404 /core/templates/404.php;

    rewrite ^/.well-known/carddav /remote.php/carddav/ permanent;
    rewrite ^/.well-known/caldav /remote.php/caldav/ permanent;

location = /robots.txt {
    allow all;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}

location ~ ^/(build|tests|config|lib|3rdparty|templates|data)/ {
    deny all;
}

location ~ ^/(?:\.|autotest|occ|issue|indie|db_|console) {
    deny all;
}

location = /robots.txt {
    allow all;
    log_not_found off;
    access_log off;
}

location ~ ^/(build|tests|config|lib|3rdparty|templates|data)/ {
    deny all;
}

location ~ ^/(?:\.|autotest|occ|issue|indie|db_|console) {
    deny all;
}

location / {

    rewrite ^/remote/(.*) /remote.php last;
    rewrite ^(/core/doc/[^\/]+/)$ $1/index.html;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location ~ \.php(?:$|/) {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
    fastcgi_param modHeadersAvailable true;
    fastcgi_pass php-handler;
    fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
}

# Adding the cache control header for js and css files
# Make sure it is BELOW the location ~ \.php(?:$|/) { block

location ~* \.(?:css|js)$ {
    add_header Cache-Control "public, max-age=7200";
    # Add headers to serve security related headers
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=15768000; includeSubDomains; preload;";
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN";
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block";
    add_header X-Robots-Tag none;
    # Optional: Don't log access to assets
    access_log off;
}


location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|bmp|ico|png|swf)$ {
    access_log off;
}
}
```

If anyone of you had an idea, i would be glad.

My environment is: Ubuntu 14.04 VPS, nginx 1.9.11, PHP5-FPM (latest with ubuntu), apparmor is off (switched it off as i experienced this error), files in /srv are readable by nginx user, i even chowned them for resolving this error, but it has no effect. Open_basedir in php has no effect (includes all relevant locations anyway, but does not resolve the error when turned off).

Comment: Are you trying to access owncloud via the web application? at what url?

Answer (score 2):

I wonder if the svg request is being sent to PHP. Try changing your last location to this

```
location ~* \.(?:jpg|jpeg|gif|bmp|ico|png|swf|svg)$ {
  access_log off;
}
```

The reason I suspect is this block, which is sending all requests for / to PHP, which is probably unnecessary

```
location ~ \.php(?:$|/) {
```

If that doesn't help you want to know what location block the request is going through. Add something like this to each of your location blocks, and view the request / response with [Live HTTP Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) and firefox (or curl, I think it's "curl -i" to get headers but I could be wrong)

```
location (whatever) {
  add_header Z_LOCATION "DESCRIBE LOCATION";
}
```